# Removing decimal to column using a function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that calls a function on a few of the columns. The results have 3 decimal places, its already being rounded but output always has "x.000".

Here is the query...

```
SELECT     SystemName, Caption, Label, 
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', Capacity) AS Capacity,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', FreeSpace) AS [Free Space], 
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', Capacity - FreeSpace) AS [Used Space],
           100 * FreeSpace / Capacity AS [% of Free Space], 
           Warning = 
    CASE 
        WHEN 100 * FreeSpace / Capacity BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN 'Proactive Warning'
        WHEN 100 * FreeSpace / Capacity <= 10 THEN 'Critical Warning'
    END

FROM         CCS_Win32_Volume
WHERE     ((100 * FreeSpace / Capacity) < 20)
ORDER BY SystemName, Caption
```

Any input is appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you sure it's always going to be zeros at the end, or do you not care about that level of precision?

Comment: for every result it is always .000 Even when i know there should be a decimal (if i wanted it shown). I j ust want to remove the 0's probably caused by the function im calling. @MauriceReeves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, change the decimal accuracy of your return type.  So, right now, I would expect the return type to be something like `decimal(18,3)`.  Which means 18 digits, three decimal places (to the right of the decimal).  Instead, change your output to use the number of decimal places that you would prefer.  For instance, if you would like zero, you could convert it to a bigint or decimal(18,0)

If you don't own the function, then you could cast the output after the function is called, but it doesn't look as nice

```
Cast([dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', Capacity) AS Decimal(18,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't care about maintaining that level of precision, you can use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX to strip off the end:

```
SUBSTRING([dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', Capacity), 0, CHARINDEX([dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', Capacity), '.')
```

It might be easier if you store the results in a temp table and then apply your formatting, and you may need to cast to varchar first.

Good luck!